# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI ....in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

Actaully i have configured my web.xml,pom.xml,disptcher-servlet.xml and controller but i am getting an error like this :

```
"org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
    WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springwebstuck/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'".
```

The question was also asked my many people but their solution didnot work for me i am posting some of my configuration files:

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ashwin</groupId>
  <artifactId>springwebstuck</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springwebstuck Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
  <java.version>7.0</java.version>
  <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>${java.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>

  </plugins>

    <finalName>springwebstuck</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   ">


   <context:component-scan base-package="com.ashwin.springwebstuck.*"/>

   <bean id="viewResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
              <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />

              <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

        </bean>
   </beans>
```

pagecontroller.java

```
package com.ashwin.springwebstuck.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(value= {"/","/home"})
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("greetings","Wleocme");
        return mv;

    }

}
```

page.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
${greetings}
</body>
</html>
```

my project structure looks like:

[image]

The http://localhost:8080/ is running :

[image]

The error i am getting is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.ashwin.springwebstuck.*"/>`

to

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.ashwin.springwebstuck"/>`